# Magento 2 : Admin reorder url link

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.4.1, reorder

i want to get redorer url of order Id in magento , please help with you to do same , unable to find any soluiton to this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to get it on frontend use below code

```
<?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder')->canReorder($_order->getEntityId())) : ?>
    <a href="#" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo
    $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper::class)
        ->getPostData($block->getReorderUrl($_order))
    ?>' class="action order">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Reorder') ?></span>
    </a>
<?php endif ?>
```

In backend it is coming from below function

`vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View.php`

```
if ($this->_isAllowedAction(
    'Magento_Sales::reorder'
) && $this->_reorderHelper->isAllowed(
    $order->getStore()
) && $order->canReorderIgnoreSalable()
) {
    $this->addButton(
        'order_reorder',
        [
            'label' => __('Reorder'),
            'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getReorderUrl() . '\')',
            'class' => 'reorder'
        ]
    );
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Reorder URL getter
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReorderUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('sales/order_create/reorder');
}
```

I hope it will help you. Thanks!

Comment: i tried below code but it did not work for amdin 

$order = $this->orderFactory->create()->load($this->getValue());
$b =  $order->getReorderUrl();